# .htaccess URL redirect old link format to new

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

Recently I've changed the link format to articles on my self-hosted wordpress blog and I want old bookmarks to be able to redirect to the new links seamlessly, so that readers don't get page not found.

The old format was:`https://domain.tld/index.php/yyyy/mm/dd/title-of-post`

The new format is: `https://domain.tld/title-of-post/`

I made this change of course because it's a lot nicer and time isn't really a factor for my blog. I'm using Apache's `RewriteRule` directive in the `.htaccess` file but I'm having trouble getting the pattern to match. This is the current state of the `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]/.*?$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

But previously I've tried such patterns as:

```
^index\.php/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)/.*?$
```

and

```
^index\.php/2018/03/30/.*?$
```

and even

```
(index)(\\.)(php)(\\/)(\\d)(\\d)(\\d)(\\d)(\\/)(\\d)(\\d)(\\/)(\\d)(\\d)(\\/)((?:[a-z][a-z]+))
```

Of which the last I tried to use txt2re

None of this gave me any luck in matching the URL I'm giving it. I want old links to redirect to the new corresponding link.

Comment: you want to redirect this https://domain.tld/index.php/yyyy/mm/dd/title-of-post to https://domain.tld/title-of-post/ ?

Comment: @SufiyanGhori yes precisely

Comment: have you tried modifying permalink settings in wordpress admin panel? wordpress should take care of such redirection

Comment: @SufiyanGhori I have, to no avail. The only thing that wordpress removes is the index.php. I've even removed the rule from the htaccess file and it still simply removes index.php

Comment: Please see the latest answer, i have added the redirection rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of modifying your `.htaccess` its a better idea to use Redirection plugin such as the following,

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/
```

it will take care of all the redirection for you

This worked for me and many others. Please let me know if this works for you.

**Edit:**

For your specific case, following rule will work

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index\.php/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ http://yourdomain.com/$4
```

You can read more on this rule here,

https://perishablepress.com/redirect-wordpress-date-archives-htaccess/

Comment: Thank you! Gosh I've been wracking my brain over this. The redirection plugin worked like a charm

Comment: Cheers! glad I helped